# Different actions at different release times

Tags: autohotkey

So i got this code which is working almost fine.. Its maybe a good starting point if u can help me.:

```
*LButton::
    Send A
KeyWait, LButton, T1
If ErrorLevel
    Send C
Else
    Send B
KeyWait, LButton
Return
```

What the code does it defines whats gonna be the release action, after i let go the LMB (left mouse button) and when.

If i release the LMB under 1 sec its gonna send **A** **B**. If i release it after 1 sec it should send **A** **C**, which it does but not after i release the LMB. It sends **C** right after the 1 sec is gone. I want to send **C** only after i release the LMB.

And if the LMB was released after 1 sec than i want to block the LMB for x time. So i coudnt hit it again.

But if it was released before 1 sec it should work normally.

English was never my bright side.. :D, hope u can understand thx.

Comment: Could you explain better what you mean by this *"And if the LMB was released after 1 sec than i want to block the LMB for x time. So i coudnt hit it again"*?

Comment: When you say *"But if it was released before 1 sec it should work normally."*, do you mean that you want it to click like the mouse normally would, or do you want to `Send A B` and not trigger the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. When you said *"And if the LMB was released after 1 sec than i want to block the LMB for x time. So i coudnt hit it again"*, you meant that you wanted it so that the clicking the LMB wouldn't do any action during the block duration.
2. You wanted it so that only if the second action was triggered (the one that sends a 'C' after a certain amount of time has passed), the block would be activated. This would allow you to repeatedly click the mouse to send A B, but you would have to wait for a second before you can send anything after A C.

Then the solution I came up with involves a toggled variable that determines whether the hotkey will do anything if the LMB is pressed. The toggle variable, `switch`, is set to disable mode after the A C part of the script activates, but after one second (1000 milliseconds), the variable goes back to the "enabled" state. [For reference, when switch is 1, the hotkey is enabled, but if it is 0, it is disabled.]

Code:

```
switch := 0

*LButton::
if(!switch){
    Send A
    KeyWait, LButton, T1
    If ErrorLevel{
        Send C
        gosub, tempBlock
    }
    Else
    Send B
    KeyWait, LButton
    Return
}
else
    return

tempBlock:
switch:=1
SetTimer, reset, -1000
return

reset:
switch:=0
return
```

Comment: C is going to be sent after 1 sec even if LMB is still held down. "else return" is also redundant.

Comment: Yeah, srry abt that @0x464e. This solution was supposed to be a quick and dirty script that built off of what OP had. 2 things though: 1. I thought that sending the C like that was the desired outcome, since that was what the original code did. 2. Yeah that else return is definitely about as redundant as it gets. That happened bc I threw a msgbox there while debugging and didn't bother to remove the else statement afterward. Anyways, aside from the difference in when the C sends (since I don't rlly know which one OP would want), your answer is definitely the cleaner and better-coded option :)

Comment: i like both of your codes i dont know if i really need the LMB block but this code does it. maybe if u can implement the blocking option for @0x464e code would be nice thx

Comment: okay after a little testing this code works better for me i accept as answer thanks all of you

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to do if you don't try to mess around with `KeyWait`.
The example below is still missing your "blocking" thing. I don't really know what you meant by it.
If it's something you won't know how to add yourself, I can add it in after you explain it better.

```
*LButton::
    ClickedAt := A_TickCount
    SendInput, A
return

LButton Up::
    if (A_TickCount - ClickedAt <= 1000)
        SendInput, B
    else
        SendInput, C
return
```

So `LButton::` is for the key being pressed down. and `LButton Up::` is for the key being released.
On the down press we store the current system uptime from the built-in variable `A_TickCount`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TickCount)</sup> and on the key release we compare the current system uptime to the stored one to see how long has passed.

[SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) is also used instead of traditional `Send`, due to `SendInput` being the recommended faster and more reliable send mode.

---

Bonus, two liner (because why not):

```
*LButton::SendInput, % ("A", ClickedAt := A_TickCount)
LButton Up::SendInput, % (A_TickCount - ClickedAt <= 1000) ? "B" : "C"
```

Comment: hey thx for the help code works very well and 2 liner is just sexy. :D what i mean by blocking is that i coudnt click LMB again for at least half a sec after it sends C. otherwise its working very well.